# Инициализация неинициализированной переменной не приводит к UB?

Tags: c++, инициализация

Почему `(1)` является `UB`, а `(2)` - нет?

```
char x;
char y = x; // (1)

unsigned char x;
unsigned char y = x; // (2)
```

Информация взята [отсюда](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization)

Comment: А это пишется внутри функции или глобально?

Comment: @pavel а разве есть разница?

Comment: Если глобально,  то я не понимаю почему 1 ub. Если локально ещё хоть как-то могу понять). А откуда этот пример взят?

Comment: @pavel тут так написано, мне тоже интересно почему 2 не `UB` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization

Comment: Мне кажется вы зря char написали, в примере int и как я понял, char   это исключение. Но ждём ответа знающих людей.

Comment: @pavel насколько я понял, именно `unsigned char` исключение

Comment: Смысла так писать конечно нету, но вопрос интересный, добавьте эту ссылку в вопрос лучше.

Comment: @pavel добавил.

Comment: Потому что так решили в комитете по стандартизации. Некоторые подробности можно обнаружить в [этом](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415661/has-c-standard-changed-with-respect-to-the-use-of-indeterminate-values-and-und) вопросе/ответе.

Comment: Есть у меня подозрение, что это связано с тем, что беззнаковые операции не могут вызывать переполнений и прочих неприятностей, а знаковые теоретически могут. Соответственно, беззнаковые числа просто имеют неопределенное значение, а знаковые - могут и программу обрушить :)

Comment: @Harry, зато выглядит как грязный костыль. Какой-то уже бред в стандарт пропихивают. Особенно пример в стандарте классный.

Comment: @ixSci это призыв к повсеместному использованию фигурных скобок

Comment: @gender, повсеместно не получится, потому что с фигурными скобками тоже не все гладко. Там столько правил, что голова кругом идёт.

Answer (score 3):

В настоящий момент имеется расхождение между C стандартом и C++ стандартом.

В стандарте зыка C написано (6.2.6 Representations of types)

> 5 Certain object representations need not represent a value of the
>   object type. If the stored value of an object has such a
>   representation and is read by an lvalue expression that **does not
>   have character type**, the behavior is undefined. If such a
>   representation is produced by a side effect that modifies all or any
>   part of the object by an lvalue expression that **does not have
>   character type**, the behavior is undefined.50) Such a representation
>   is called a trap representation.

Так называемый символьный тип (`character type`) определяется в стандарте C следующим образом (6.2.5 Types):

> 15 The three types char, signed char, and unsigned char are
>   collectively called the character types. The implementation shall
>   define char to have the same range, representation, and behavior as
>   either signed char or unsigned char

Интересно отметить, что в стандарте C++ нет определения термина `character type`, хотя этот термин используется, и под ним подразумевается аналогичное определение как обобщенное название типов `char`, `signed char` и `unsigned char`.

Итак, в стандарте языка C говорится о неопределенном поведении, когда объект не имеет (любой) символьный тип.

В стандарте C++ 2014, как я понимаю, при инициативе Страуструпа, решили уточнить в частности, и это положение о неопределенном поведении в отношении символьных типов. Там указали, что исключением является только беззнаковый символьный тип (`unsigned char`)

> 12 If no initializer is speciﬁed for an object, the object is
>   default-initialized. When storage for an object with automatic or
>   dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an indeterminate
>   value, and if no initialization is performed for the object, that
>   object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced
>   (5.18). [Note: Objects with static or thread storage duration are
>   zero-initialized, see 3.6.2. — end note] If an indeterminate value is
>   produced by an evaluation, the behavior is undeﬁned except in the
>   following cases:

....

> (12.3)   -  If an indeterminate value of unsigned narrow character
>   type is produced by the evaluation of the initialization expression
>   when initializing an object of unsigned narrow character type, that
>   object is initialized to an indeterminate value.

Я думаю, что это уточнение в стандарте C++ 2014 связано с тем, что для некоторых систем представления целочисленных значений для отдельных аппаратных архитектур для знакового символьного типа также имеется в наличии так называемое trap-представление. Например, отрицательный ноль может быть таким представлением, не допустимым для представления валидных чисел.

Comment: Может у [The Machine](https://www.extremetech.com/computing/240248-hp-demonstrates-next-generation-computing-prototype-machine-comes-together) планируется *тэгировання память*? Но тогда и с беззнаковыми целыми тоже trap-ситуация возможна. Наверное вскоре очередное дополнение о UB в стандарт напишут.

Comment: отрицательный ноль для целых типов?

Comment: @alexolut Да, именно для целых чисел. Из C стандарта "In the case of sign and
magnitude and ones’ complement, if this representation is a normal value it is called a
negative zero."

Comment: @alexolut "ones’ complement" - это одно из возможных представлений целых чисел.